# upload text file to mulitple ftp servers

Tags: c#

I am newbie to c# and working on this code to upload single  text file (csv file) to 13 (cameras) ftp locations. I don't know how to do this with one button click event.
I am working on this code it works well for one site but how can i do that for 12 other (cameras) ftp locations.how to pass mutliple ftp adddress in an array

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           UploadBlacklistFile(string ftpServerUrl,string filename);

        }
             void UploadBlacklistFile(string ftpServerUrl,string filename)
            {
            Boolean ftpMode = true;

            //// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            //FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://158.125.161.83");
            //request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFileWithUniqueName;

            //// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("superuser", "superuser");

            if (ftpMode == true)
            {
                request.KeepAlive = false;
            }
            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("C://blacklist/ticketsblacklist.csv");
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();

    string [] ftpaddress = ({"100.100.100.85","parm","parm"};{"101.101.101.85","parm1","parm1"})

    foreach(string addr in ftpaddress)
{
    uploadFile(addr, @"C:/blacklist/ticketsblacklist.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Put the code in a method that accepts an FTP url:

```
public void UploadBlacklistFile(string ftpServerUrl) { ... }
```

And call that method in a loop where you loop through all server names:

```
foreach (string serverUrl in serverUrls)
{
    UploadBlacklistFile(serverUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem. An obvious one would be to just copy and paste your code 12 times (although that isn't very clean and the people on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would probably beat you up if you did it.

Here's how I would do it:

1. Create a method (say `UploadFile(string url, string filename)`) and copy all the code that does the file uploading in there.
2. Create a string array which stores all the FTP addresses (for instance `string[] addresses={"1.2.3.4","4.3.2.1",...};`)
3. Iterate over the array using a `foreach`-loop and call the function.

   ```
   foreach(string addr in addresses)
   {
       UploadFile(addr, @"C:\yourfile.txt");
   }
   ```

That should work.

### Update

Regarding the username and password situation:

You would probably be best of with something like this:

```
string[,] addresses = 
{
    {"100.100.100.85","username","password"},
    {"100.100.100.86","username2","password2"},
    // ...
};

foreach(string[] addr in addresses)
{
    UploadFile(addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], @"C:\yourfile.txt");
}

void UploadFile(string address, string user, string password, string filename)
{
    // upload
}
```

Comment: I ahve changed the code but I am struggling to pass the addresses as array.

Comment: Would you mind editing your original question and adding the new code?

Comment: I don't understand this bit of code: `string [] ftpaddress = ({"100.100.100.85","parm","parm"};{"101.101.101.85","parm1","parm1"})`

Why the "parm"/"parm1"?

Comment: i was passing ftp adrress, username, password

Comment: Okay, passing usernames and passwords will be a bit more complicated. I would solve that by creating a 2-dimensional array like this `string[,] ftpaddress = {{"100.100.100.85","user1","pass1"},{"100.100.100.85","user2","pass2"},...};`
...but then you would also have to edit the foreach loop

Comment: FYI : U can login with  `ftp://user:pw@ftp.com` as URL, so u can store everything in one string

Comment: I still get errors Hackercow. Cannot convert type 'string' to 'string[]' on for each loop